# Centralized Version Control and Distributed Version Control

Tags: operating-system

What is the Difference between **Centralized Version Control(CVC)** and **Distributed Version Control**?

Answer (score 0):

Centralised Version Control is based on client server network which keeps a track of changes made on the central server where the latest version of work is being requested by everyone and push the latest modifications to.If central server goes down,no one can send requests to get the work or push the latest modifications
eg:Perforce andSVN

Distributed version is based on peer to peer network where all the people has a local copy of all the versions of the work.
eg:Git,Mercurial and Bazaar

Comment: Thank you! your answer is very helpful